# How to wrap each new line in textarea with li tags? PHP

Tags: php, textarea

I have a textarea form field where users will put URL's separated by a new line. Would it be possible to wrap each line from this textarea field with < li > tags?

So I would need the output from the field to be something like this:

```
<li>some.url.com</li>
<li>some.url.com</li>
<li>some.url.com</li>
<li>some.url.com</li>
<li>some.url.com</li>
```

Does anyone know who to achive this with PHP please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$textareaData = '<li>'.str_replace("\n","</li>\n<li>",trim($textareaData,"\n")).'</li>';
```

**EDIT**

Modified to get rid of all blank lines as well:

```
$textareaData = '<li>'.str_replace(array("\r","\n\n","\n"),array('',"\n","</li>\n<li>"),trim($textareaData,"\n\r")).'</li>';
```

Comment: Thanks Mark this works great. If I could just somehow omit empty lines as well it would be perfect!

Answer (score 2):

And what about something like this

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.+)(\s*)$/m', '<li>$1</li>', $text);
```

Output will be anything like this (not nice, but usefull):

```
<li>dsadsa
</li>
<li>dsdsa
</li>
<li>dsadsad
</li>
<li>dsadsadsad
</li>
<li>vcxvxcvxvcxvcx
</li>
<li>fdsfdsfdsfs
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression you can check for non-empty lines as part of your test:

```
$li_text = preg_replace('/^(.+)$/', '<li>$1</li>', $_POST['textarea']);
```

That way if the user has an extra new line at the end of their input (or anywhere inside) you won't get extra empty list items.

Comment: This would be great but can't get it to work.
It doesn't put the li tags to anything coming from the textarea but hardcoded data works.
Btw I got the content coming from the textarea as a variable if that makes a difference.

Comment: Update: it works fine if there is only 1 line of text in the textarea. If there are more than 1 line it doesn't add any li tags.

Comment: Edited to add a multi-line regex option.